# OSX - where to put my command line binary launchdaemon and dependant dylibs

Tags: macos, filesystems, installation, pkgbuild, launch-daemon

I have a command line application (not .app bundle), a single executable file. It runs from e.g. `usr/bin/myapp` . This should be accessible by all users in the mac. It is a LaunchDaemon and run as a as `root` user. If I keep it in `usr/bin` it works fine.

When a user install the app, `pkgbuild` copy the file to `/usr/bin` and `postinstall` script starts the LaunchDaemon.

The app depends on `nss` library. so now I need to copy the nss binary and dylib files to somewhere e.g. `usr/bin/lib/nss` folder. Is it possible to do using `pkgbuild` or `preinstall` script? Since `pkgbuild --install-location` set to `/usr/bin` will copy `myapp` there, but how to copy nss folder to `usr/lib`?

The other option is to make a whole folder structure `/usr/bin/MyApp` and copy my `myapp` binary file there and keep `nss` files at `/usr/bin/MyApp/nss` folder. But is that a good idea?

Or should I make the file structure at `/usr/local/MyApp` ?
Which is the best location to run myapp LaunchDaemon as a root user?
`/usr/local` or `usr/bin` or some other place?

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at antivirus programs for the Mac and where they keep their files. That's how I think I have learned to answer your question:

If you absolutely must, then install your command in /usr/bin on older systems and /usr/local/bin on newer systems. (I think when OSX 10.10 shipped, they switched to /usr/local/bin, but don't know the version exactly.) The only real reason why you want to put something there is so that your product consumers can open a terminal window and run commands. If you're not doing that, then you don't need to put it there.

So, if someone isn't meant to type your command in a terminal window, and if you don't need to run with special privileges, and if your my.app is the only thing calling it, then then you should put the command in your /Applications/my.app/Contents/Resources folder.

Now, if none of that applies to you, then you should create the command in a /Library/Application Support/[my product name] folder if it applies to all users and ~/Library/Application Support/[my product name] folder if it applies only to the current user. Now, one problem you may have is folder name collision here. So, instead of "my product name", you could do it the Java folder way, like for instance what the Opera browser does for their product: ~/Library/Application Support/com.operasoftware.Opera.

As for supporting libraries for your LaunchDaemon or LaunchAgent, then you can install them in either /Library/Application Support/[my product name] or ~/Library/Application Support/[my product name]. The latter one with the tilde (~) means it only applies to a certain user, while the other one would apply to all users.